# write regex equivalent to like statement in query

Tags: python, regex

i have sample query

```
 select c.name , c.id from company c where
 c.name like 'Hoder%' and c.name like 'Stock%' amd c.name like 'Colour%'
 and c.name like '%Delete' and c.name like '%Regular' and c.name like '%Filler'
 and c.name like '%wipe%' and c.name like '%palce%' and c.name like '%double%',
 and c.name in ('IT', 'Wall', SpyCorp', 'Signal')
```

from the above query i know the list of words, i am implementing the query with the regex
form above i wrote a regex like

```
#for exact matching words 
pnexact = ['IT', 'Wall', SpyCorp', 'Signal']
regexact = [re.compile(r"\b%s\b" % word.lower() ) for word in pnexact]#list of regex object
#for words which are contain in the string eg: '%wipe%' ...
pncontains = ['wipe','palce','double',]
pnregexobj_contains = re.compile(r"%s" % '|'.join(pncontains)) #single regex object
```

the above regex are working fine but i am not able to write regex which will hanle the case of words `'Hoder%','Stock%','Color%'` 
and the case `%Delete','%Regular','%Filler'`
please suggest me regex which will handle the above two cases

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `%` with `.*`.  For example, to match words like `%Delete` use:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'\b.*Delete\b', 'NoDelete')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100456100>
>>> _.group()
'NoDelete'
>>> re.match(r'\b.*Delete\b', 'Mismatch')
```

Comment: i wrote this regex reg = re.compile(r'(\.*)delete$') for the '%delete' the string ends with the word delete.is it fine ?

Comment: I don't think you want to backslash-escape the `.` since that turns it into a literal `.` character, but the correct regex for equivalence with `LIKE '%Delete'` should indeed be `.*Delete$`, or just `Delete$`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
m = lambda regex: re.match(regex, name)

m(r'.*Delete$') # name like %Delete
m(r'Delete')    # name like Delete%
m(r'.*Delete')  # name like %Delete%
```

To find out whether `name` is one of words:

```
pnexact = ['IT', 'Wall', 'SpyCorp', 'Signal'] # use `set()` if the list is long
name in pnexact # name in ('IT', 'Wall', 'SpyCorp', 'Signal')
```

Or if you'd like to use a regex:

```
m(r"^(?:%s)$" % "|".join(map(re.escape, pnexact)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:  `WHERE c.name like 'Hoder%' and c.name like 'Stock%'`

is equivalent to: `WHERE False`

A column (like `c.name`) cannot start from `Hoder` and `Stock`  at the same time.

You probably meant to use `OR` and not `AND`.